# What effects do we have to take in account to calculate the total precession of a gyroscope orbiting close to a black hole?

Tags: general-relativity, special-relativity, gravity, black-holes, precession

I've read about the [Lense–Thirring precession](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lense%E2%80%93Thirring_precession) which applies to bodies orbiting rotating masses. But there is also the [geodetic effect (de Sitter precession)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geodetic_effect), which is caused by the curvature of spacetime.

But a gyroscope orbiting in the ISCO of a black hole would be travelling at relativistic speeds, and I've also read about [Thomas precession](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thomas_precession), which is caused by the [Wigner rotation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wigner_rotation) (a sequence of non-colinear Lorentz boosts that equals a single boost and a rotation).

Do we have to take all of this effects or more into consideration? How do they add up?

Answer (score 1):

You have to include all effects (of course) but a given precession can be interpreted differently depending on what coordinates are adopted. That is, there is an absolute, objective result such as the angle between the angular momentum and the direction to a distant star or similar, but whether we ascribe that angle to Thomas, Lense-Thirring or de Sitter, or a combination thereof, depends on what coordinate frame is used. In practice one often just does a calculation using parallel transport without ever bothering to find out which effects are in play.

Having said that, if the gravitating mass is not itself rotating then one would normally say the Lense-Thirring precession is zero.

Answer (score 0):

> Stellar_Enginner asked: *"Do we have to take all of this effects or more into consideration? How do they add up?"*

First you solve the [geodesic equation](http://yukterez.net/f/einstein.equations/files/67.html#9)

$$\rm \ddot{x}^{\mu}=-\sum_{\sigma , \kappa} \ \Gamma^{\mu}_{\sigma \kappa} \ \dot{x}^{\sigma} \ \dot{x}^{\kappa} \ $$

or the [Hamilton Jacobi](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Hakan-Cebeci-5/publication/288890529_Motion_of_the_charged_test_particles_in_Kerr-Newman-Taub-NUT_spacetime_and_analytical_solutions/links/568a9ed808aebccc4e1a0dba/Motion-of-the-charged-test-particles-in-Kerr-Newman-Taub-NUT-spacetime-and-analytical-solutions.pdf#page=6) equation

$$\rm  p_{\mu}=\frac{\partial S}{\partial x^{\mu}} \ , \ \  \dot{S}= \sum_{\sigma , \kappa} \ \frac{g^{\sigma \kappa}}{2} \ \frac{\partial S}{\partial x^{\sigma}} \ \frac{\partial S}{\partial x^{\kappa}}$$

for the orbit and then you do the [parallel transport](https://notizblock.yukterez.net/viewtopic.php?p=1050#equations) of the gyroscope's vector

$$\rm \dot{V}^{\mu}=-\sum_{\sigma , \kappa} \ \Gamma^{\mu}_{\sigma \kappa} \ V^{\sigma} \ \dot{x}^{\kappa} \ $$

along that path, that way you don't need to add up all the single components you mentioned above, but in general the integration over time ($\rm \dot{x}=dx/d\tau , \ \rm \ddot{x}=d^2x/d\tau^2$) has to be done numerically.